# Ubuntu 16.04 - Can't run software update or apt-get-update

Tags: 16.04, apt, update-manager

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I haven't been able to update the software in months because I keep getting this message. I tried switching between servers. That's not it. Tried updating the expired keys. Still no luck. Please help me resolve this. I can't even upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu to fix it. Nothing works.

I am also wondering if this has to do with the Trust software providers section of the software updated being empty. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Software Updater gives me the following:

> Failed to download repository information. Check your internet
>   conntection.

Can't run `sudo-apt-get-update`. I get this message:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease 
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release            
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease    
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease   
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gambas-team/gambas3/ubuntu xenial InRelease                               
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                    
Ign:8 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04 InRelease 
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/i-nex-development-team/daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:12 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04 Release 
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:16 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease 
Err:17 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04 Release.gpg   
The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244 Reading package lists... Done  
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04 Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.gpg The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244 
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.gpg The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244 
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I then tried updating the keys:

```
for K in $(apt-key list | grep expired | cut -d '/' -f2 | cut -d' '-f1); do sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net $K; done
```

And output:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.5NRsQ5oSoL/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net BEB6D886 gpg: requesting key BEB6D886 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net gpg: key BEB6D886: "home:Horst3180 OBS

Project <home:Horst3180@build.opensuse.org>" not changed gpg: Total number processed: 1 gpg: unchanged: 1 Executing: /tmp/tmp.ctjucxHt4s/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys

--keyserver keys.gnupg.net F6D61D45 gpg: requesting key F6D61D45 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net gpg: key F6D61D45: "Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2015 <packager@opera.com>" 
not changed gpg: Total number processed: 1 gpg: unchanged: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GPG key for opensuse repository has expired.

If you don't need this source, comment the source entries with this command:

```
sudo sed -i '/opensuse/ s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

And run this command for delete expired key:

```
sudo apt-key del 1496576244
```

Then run this command for update repositories:

```
sudo apt update
```